# Error in Saving of Regarding Attribute (Lead_PhoneCall Activity) from CRM Portal (2011)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am trying to save Guid of Lead in Regarding Field of PhoneCall Activity,
It gives an error like - "regardingobjectid" only. [On Premise]

Please Help!

In New_PhoneCall.cs Page :

PhoneCall_Save.regardingobjectid = Guid.Parse(hdnfld_regarding.Value); //(hdnfld_regarding is a hiddenfield in which m passing guid, which i have taken along with textbox)

In AppCode/CRMDMLibrary.cs :

```
    public class PhoneEntity
    {
       public Guid regardingobjectid;
    }

    public bool SaveNewPhoneCall()
    {
        try
        {
            IOrganizationService Context = CRMDMLibrary.GetCRMService(url, DomainName, username, password);

            Entity Phone = new Entity("phonecall");

            Phone["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference("regardingobject", regardingobjectid);

            Guid phoneid = Context.Create(Phone);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.Message);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing regardingobject as **EntityReference** is wrong.You should pass **lead** as 
EntityReference

```
 Phone.Attributes["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference("lead", regardingobjectid);
```

Also Check that where **lead** id is coming from